# Restore data from tar file

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.1, centos

I have a tar archive with full backup of my CentOS filesystem with PostgreSQL 9.1 installed.

How can I restore one database from it?

If I can only restore a full database cluster, how can I do that? Just copy-paste all the files?

Answer (score 3):

You will need a locally installed PostgreSQL of the same major as the data directory archive. For example, if the archive came from 9.1.5 you would need some 9.1.x on the local machine, it doesn't matter if it's 9.1.0 or 9.1.9, but it must be 9.1 not 9.2 or 9.0.

If you don't have 9.1, you can install it from packages or just download the source and compile it locally.

Then, if you just want to dump the data to reload into an existing local PostgreSQL install:

- Unpack the archive
- If necessary set your `PATH` so that PostgreSQL 9.1's `bin` directory is first on the `PATH`
- `PGPORT=5435 pg_ctl -D /path/to/unpacked/archive start`
- `PGPORT=5435 pg_dumpall --globals-only`
- Dump each database with `pg_dump`

If you instead want to restore the database so it runs instead of whatever's locally running, you must:

- Ensure the current install is of the same major version
- Stop the current PostgreSQL: `service postgresql stop`
- Rename the data directory. On CentOS it'll be in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/`, so something like `sudo mv /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data.old`. **Do not delete it**; if it turns out there is data in there you forgot you needed, this way you can still get it back.
- Move the unpacked archive to the old data directory location, e.g `sudo mv /path/to/unpacked/archive/folder /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data`
- Set the permissions: `sudo chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data; sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data`
- Edit `postgresql.conf` to reflect any required changes for the local install
- Start PostgreSQL: `service postgresql start`

Some details like service name, path, etc will vary depending on whether you're running the original Red Hat packages of PostgreSQL, or whether you installed from http://yum.postgresql.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>Answer originally left in comments by the OP and [Igor Romanchenko](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/15485/igor-romanchenko):</sub>*

Copy the `postgres` data directory from the archive and launch `postgres` for the copied data directory.

I copied the `postgres` centos data directory to the ubuntu data directory

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main
```

(It is similar to data). After restarting, I had an error:

> - Error: could not exec
>
>   ```
>   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl
>       /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl 
>       start -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main
>       -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
>       -s -o  
>       -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf"
>   ```

After restoring the backup to the right place I still got this error.

I finally solved the problem by changing the owner of the `/var/lib/PostgreSQL` folder.